# How do I print the minimum?

Tags: python, function

What should I do in order to print the minimum number? In this code I can only print the maximum number. For example, the highest number in this code is 1000 right, it means 1000 will be printed. How do I make 500 the printed one?

```py
work_hours = [("Jao", "Ville",1000), ("Billy", "Jackson St", 900),("Kevin", "Westside", 500)]

def employee_check(work_hours):
    current_max = 0
    employee_of_month = ''
    employee_of_month_location = ''
#jangan lupa untuk assign location juga di ''
    for employee,location,hours in work_hours:
        if hours > current_max:
            current_max = hours
            employee_of_month = employee
            employee_of_month_location = location
        else:
            pass

    return employee_of_month, employee_of_month_location, current_max

result  = employee_check(work_hours)

print(result)
```

Comment: Think about what you might change in `if hours > current_max:` in particular to pick out the lowest number instead of the highest.

Comment: Do you understand the logic applied for maximum? How would you reverse it? Of course there is much simple solution, but assuming you wrote this - let's start with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach: Python has a `min` function which also accepts a `key` parameter for further instructions on how to define the minimum. In this case we want to compare the last elements of each tuple in `work_hours`, i.e. `x[2]`:

```
work_hours = [("Jao", "Ville",1000),
              ("Billy", "Jackson St", 900), 
              ("Kevin", "Westside", 500)]

result = min(work_hours, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

This replaces all of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Check with the condition :

```
hours > current_max
```

This can be easily solved when understanding what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to reorganize your list work_hours putting the hours (integer number) as first element. Example:
work_hours = [(1000, "Jao", "Ville"), (900, "Billy", "Jackson St"),(500, "Kevin", "Westside")]

Then, you can simply use the method min(work_hours), which will return (500, 'Kevin', 'Westside') in this case.